# Why can't I select anything within this variable?

Tags: powershell

I cannot select any from the `$results2` variable. When I display the variable by itself, it display all the information how it should, I just can't pipe it and Select-Object.

```
$exists = $true
            while ($exists -eq $true) {
                $search = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter first name or surname name of user, or enter [x] to quit to main menu"
                if ($search -ne 'x') {
                    $results = @(Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$search*'")
                    if ($results) {
                        $i=1
                        $results2 = $results | Select-Object @{ Name = "ID" ; Expression= {$Global:i;$Global:i++}}, Name, SamAccountName | Format-Table
                        $results2
                        $id = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter ID you want to reset"
                        $user = $results2 | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "$id"}
                        $user
```

`$results2` output:

```
ID Name        SamAccountName
-- ----        --------------
 1 Conor Timms Conor.Timms
 2 Conor Admin ConorAdmin
```

Comment: First of all you should remove the `Format-Table` on your command line where you define the variable.  ;-)

Comment: Your code appears to be missing at least 3 `}`'s, please fix it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I intentionally left them out as the rest of the code is redundant to the problem

Comment: @Olaf When I remove the `Format-Table` it doesn't output the result in the next line

Comment: If you want to output it a certain way you shoud add the `Format-Table` then. But if you want to use its properties afterwards you should keep it an object with properties.

Comment: @ConorTimms Then change the next line from `$results2` to `$results2 | Format-Table` <-- only use `Format-*` cmdlets _at the point in time you want to output_

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the info! Still no results with this variable `$user = $results2 | Where-Object ID -eq "$id" `

Comment: What do you have in `$_.ID` and in `$id`?

Comment: $results2[0].ID = 1 $results2[1].ID = 2

Comment: @ConorTimms Did you type any additional whitespace characters when entering the ID in the prompt? Give `Where-Object { $_.ID -eq "$id".Trim()}` a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping to `Format-*` cmdlets is the *last thing* you'll want to do.

Think of `Format-Table` as a *laminator*. You feed it a piece of paper, it'll spit it out laminated - very pretty, easy to read - but you can no longer edit the text on the paper.

Instead, only call `Format-*` when you're ready to output to the screen:

```
# this statement is supposed to process/calculate data we'll need later - NO FORMATTING HERE!
$results2 = $results | Select-Object @{ Name = "ID" ; Expression= {$Global:i;$Global:i++}}, Name, SamAccountName

# this statement is supposed to show the table in the host application - good time to use `Format-Table`
$results2 |Format-Table

# Make sure you trim the input for any excess whitespace
$id = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter ID you want to reset" |ForEach-Object Trim

# Same story here as above - separate data processing from formatting/presentation
$user = $results2 | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq "$id"}
$user |Format-Table
```